# How to split of string and for each determined character found add a new line

Tags: c#, .net, string

For example:

I have this:

```
string commaSeparatedString = "124,45415,1212,4578,233,968,6865,32545,4545";
```

I want to do that **for each 4** found comma add a new line

```
124-45415-1212-4578
233-968-6865-32545
4545
```

Comment: Have a look at `string.Split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const int batch = 4;
var target = "124,45415,1212,4578,233,968,6865,32545,4545";
var items = target.Split(',');
var results = new List<string>();

var continue = false;
var step = 0;
do
{
    var slide = items.Skip(step++ * batch).Take(batch);
    continue = slide.Count() == batch;
    results.Add(string.Join('-', slide));
}while(continue);
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
string str = "124,45415,1212,4578,233,968,6865,32545,4545";
var result = string.Join("-", sss.Split(',').Select((c, index) => (index + 1) % 4 == 0 ?
                              c + Environment.NewLine : c));
```

Just don't forget to add [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to your using directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: you could do this: `string.Join("", str.Split(',').Select((c, i) => (i != 0) && ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) ? c + Environment.NewLine : c + "-"))`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(SplitOnChar("124,45415,1212,4578,233,968,6865,32545,4545",',',4));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string SplitOnChar(string input, char theChar, int number)
    {
        string result = "";
        int seen = 0;
        int lastSplitIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i< input.Length;i++)
        {
            char c = input[i];
            if (c.Equals(theChar))
            {
                seen++;
                if (seen == number)
                {
                    result += input.Substring(lastSplitIndex + 1, i - lastSplitIndex -1);
                    result += Environment.NewLine;
                    lastSplitIndex = i;
                    seen = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        result += input.Substring(lastSplitIndex + 1);
        result = result.Replace(theChar, '-');
        return result;
    }
}
}
```